# My ranges duplicate themselves when I try attach them at an email VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The process I am doing is simple, I have a table which I filter, I apply the first filters, then save the table as a range, clear the filters and apply the second filters, save this second range as a different one. Then attach both ranges in the email. But it always seems to be the same range, or almost the same.

```
Sub Emailrange()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim count_row, count_col As Integer
    Dim Table1 As range
    Dim table2 As range
    Dim str1, str2, str3 As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    'Primera Parte
        
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Cells.Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    range("G1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
        
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    ActiveSheet.range("$A$1:$N$390").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="API"
    ActiveSheet.range("$A$1:$N$390").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="=BLOQUEO VT", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
    ActiveSheet.range("$A$1:$N$390").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Luch"
    ActiveSheet.range("$A$1:$N$390").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="#N/A"
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    
    'Creamos la tabla
    With Sheets("Accepted Followup")
        count_row = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.range("A1", .range("A1").End(xlDown)))
        count_col = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.range("A1", .range("A1").End(xlToRight)))
        Set Table1 = .range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(count_row, count_col))
   End With
   
   Set GetData1 = Table1

 ' Segunda parte

    Selection.AutoFilter
    Cells.Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    range("G1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.range("$A$1:$N$390").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:= _
    "=BLOQUEO VT", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
    ActiveSheet.range("$A$1:$N$390").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="True"
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=0
    ActiveSheet.range("$A$1:$N$390").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="Aceptado"
    ActiveSheet.range("$A$1:$N$390").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="="
    ActiveSheet.range("$A$1:$N$390").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Luch"
    Columns("G:CB").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    With Sheets("Accepted Followup")
    count_row = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.range("A1", .range("A1").End(xlDown)))
    count_col = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.range("A1", .range("A1").End(xlToRight)))
    Set table2 = .range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(count_row, count_col))
    End With

    Set GetData2 = table2

'Correo
    str1 = "<BODY STYLE = font-size12pt/font-family:Calibri>" & "Good morning,<br>”"
    str2 = "<br>Please see below.<br>"
    str3 = "<br>Best regards."

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "rudy@lucian.es"
        .CC = " "
        .Subject = "Tables"
        .Display
        .HTMLBody = str1 & str2 & RangetoHTML(table2) & RangetoHTML(Table1) & "<br> <br>" & .HTMLBody
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have filtered data use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to define the ranges.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Emailrange()

    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
    Dim Table1 As Range, Table2 As Range, lastrow As Long
    Dim str1, str2, str3 As String
    
    With Sheets("Accepted Followup")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Columns.Hidden = False
        .Range("G1").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        .Columns("G:G").Hidden = True
        With .Range("$A$1:$N$" & lastrow)
        
            'Creamos la tabla
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Luch"
            .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="#N/A"
            .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="=BLOQUEO VT", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
            .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="API"
            Set Table1 = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            'MsgBox Table1.Address
           
            ' Segunda parte
            .Parent.Columns("G:G").Hidden = False
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Luch"
            .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="True"
            .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="=BLOQUEO VT", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
            .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="Aceptado"
            .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="="
            Set Table2 = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            'MsgBox table2.Address
            
        End With
        .Columns("G:CB").Hidden = True
    End With

    'Correo
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    str1 = "<BODY STYLE = font-size12pt/font-family:Calibri>" & "Good morning,<br>"
    str2 = "<br>Please see below.<br>"
    str3 = "<br>Best regards."

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "rudy@lucian.es"
        .CC = " "
        .Subject = "Tables"
        .Display
        .HTMLBody = str1 & str2 & Table2.Address & "<hr/>" & _
                    Table1.Address & "<br> <br>" & .HTMLBody
        '.HTMLBody = str1 & str2 & RangetoHTML(Table2) & RangetoHTML(Table1) & "<br> <br>" & .HTMLBody
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @CDP1802 but I would like to paste the different tables in the email, this pastes me the address right?

Comment: @Marta Yes, since I don't have RangetoHTML() I used address to check it was working and that the ranges are different. Replace the .HTMLBody line with the one commented out underneath

Comment: It stil doesnt work, it prints me the different addresses but not the table, which has two rows if I do it manually. I believe it might be because if the range changes it doesnt print the table you saved before.

Comment: @Marta Add the code for `RangetoHTML()` to your question.